# position footer at bottom of page using absolute and top

Tags: html, css, position, pdf-generation

I'm creating a page that is going to be parsed to a PDF document by [ASPPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/).

I need a footer for the page, it's prefered that the footer is repeated on evry page of the PDF but if it's on the last page thats fine to as long as it's at the bottom of the page. ASPPDF cannot read fixed positioning and it can only read absolute positioning with the top and left css attributes.

So this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4stQ/)

html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="otherContent">
        loads of content
          <div id="footer">
               The footers content
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#page
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
#otherContent
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

shows what result I would like and just replacing bottom with top gives me [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/5r5ps/), which is not the result I want.

html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="otherContent">
        loads of content
          <div id="footer">
               The footers content
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#page
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
#otherContent
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #f00;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that u may to get out the footer element from the content page and treat it in a different way.

Also, your content div has a specified height. If u refill that div with things that exceeds the limit, it will supperpose your footer.

I don't understand all what u want, but there's my solution for the problem i think that you have:

```
CSS:
    #page
    {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
    }
    #otherContent
    {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px dashed #f00; 
        width: 100%;
    }
    #footer {
            width: 100%;
            position:relative;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
        }
    }

HTML

<div id="page">
    <div id="otherContent">
      LOOOOOOTS OF CONTENTS
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
               The footers content
          </div>
</div>
```

There's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5r5ps/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css code

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -3em;
}
```

for more best tutorials about the layout and the footer visit
http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/